# Generating PBF files on request similar to renderd/mod_tile PNG tiles

Tags: pbf

I am trying to build my own fantasy map with history information. I am running the website fork of OSM from https://www.openhistoricalmap.org/. I got the site running but the default layer is requesting PBF files (for example https://vtiles.openhistoricalmap.org/maps/osm/8/72/122.pbf). That looks like something the default OpenStreetMap website layers do with PNG tiles.

I managed to build a tile server using mod_tile/renderd that generates, on request, PNG tiles.

How do I set up a similar tile server for those pbf files? Also, if the idea is to generate *all* pbf files, I am interested how should I do it. Is it done with osmosis?

I am quite fresh with this technology so just pointing me to correct program/technology names might be enough.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The correct application is https://tegola.io/.

It can split data from GIS database, on request, onto splitted PBH files.